# Can I make a user command non-silent?

Tags: neovim, user-commands

### Summary

I use a command and it prints a message. When I create a user command that runs the same underlying function, I don't see the message.

### Example

The command `:Telescope git_status` from the [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) plugin shows information about `git status`. When there are no git changes, it will print the following message:

```
No changes found
[telescope.builtin.git_status]: No changes found
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I like this message and I want to see it.

Here is my custom user command:

```lua
local telescopeBuiltins = require('telescope.builtin')
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Gs',
    function()
        vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('<ESC>', true, false, true), 'n', false)
        return telescopeBuiltins.git_status()
    end,
    {bang = true}
)
```

However, when I run `:Gs`, I just see nothing on the cmdline. For some reason, the user command is executing "silently" and not showing the error message.

Comment: Your function doesn’t run `:Telescope git_status` though; what happens if you do that instead?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble if I change it to `vim.cmd(':Telescope git_status')` instead of `telescopeBuiltins.git_status()`, I get the same result. I should mention that the functionality works fine when there are actual git changes, i.e. I'm successfully calling the correct underlying function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you assigned `telescopeBuiltins` to `require("telescope.builtin")`, in which case you should be able to do this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
    "Gs",
    telescopeBuiltins.git_status,
    { bang = true }
)
```

If you want to pass arguments to your command, that then get passed to the `git_status` function, you can wrap it in an anonymous function:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
    "Gs",
    function(tbl) telescopeBuiltins.git_status(tbl.args) end,
    { bang = true, nargs = "?" }
)
```

Edit: I just wanted to clarify that, when defining a user command, a table of information is passed to the provided function by default (see `:help nvim_create_user_command`). If you don't want this table passed along to the API call, the call should be wrapped in an anonymous function.

Comment: Yes, `telescopeBuiltins` is equal to `require('telescope.builtin')`. I edited the question to amend that.

Your suggestion worked; I changed `function() telescopeBuiltins.git_status() end` to `telescopeBuiltins.git_status` and it worked how I wanted it to. Any ideas why enclosing it in a function changed the behavior?

Comment: Good question! Maybe it has something to do with the `return`? I'm not sure, to be honest.